# Can we write SOQL query to fetch set the records which are in Trigger.New in before trigger?

Tags: trigger, soql

Can we write SOQL query to fetch set the records which are in Trigger.New in before trigger

Comment: Which `before` trigger? Obviously not for `before insert`, as they have not yet hit the database.

Comment: Why? They are already part of the trigger. Knowing what you are trying to do would get better answered. Right now the answer is “depends”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  You could use

```
[SELECT MyField FROM MyObject WHERE Id IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet()];
```

I'm not sure why you would need to though, since, as @sfdcfox mentioned, you could reference the values in Trigger.old and save yourself a query.

Comment: Thanks, It is asked in an interview. so I asked. But people are very much intelligent and mentioning that questing is not proper.

Comment: Careful!  That's the kind of interview question I'd ask, hoping you'd say, "why would you need to?"    ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you query the records in a before trigger, you will see the records' state as it exists in the database before saving. For inserts, no records are returned, and for updates and deletes, the values in Trigger.old are returned.